# Usage and origins of 打机

Tags: etymology, cantonese, topolect

In Cantonese, 打机 is used colloquially to refer to playing video or computer games. Where does the expression/word come from, and is it also used in Mandarin? If not, what is a similar Mandarin expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Mainland China, we say"打游戏", more information about the"打機" can be found here: [http://evchk.wikia.com/wiki/打機](http://evchk.wikia.com/wiki/%E6%89%93%E6%A9%9F)

Answer (score 2):

I can only answer the mandarin part, we never say 打机 in Mandarin. But we will say

> 打游戏 玩游戏 打电动 玩电脑 打电玩

And 打机 looks like 打飞机...which is kind of weird and embarrassing.